# Improve backspace support in multiple lines

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I use `std::cin.get(c)` to get input stuff to my program. Whether there is an existing solution to improve features:

Support backspace. Important: If I have a line, which more than one line in terminal, standard solution like:

```
case 0x7f:
std::cout << "\x1b\x5b\x44";
std::cout << " ";
std::cout << "\x1b\x5b\x44";
```

Doesn't work.

What's a simplest easiest way to do this?

Comment: Depending on what your program is doing, it might make more sense to use ncurses.